# Scripts menu not shown on GeoServer Web Admin Interface after installing the Scripting extension

Tags: python, geoserver, wps, geoserver-manager

I want to run a custom WPS processing on GeoServer.

I followed the tutorial
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/scripting/index.html

to install and enable Scripting extension on my GeoServer 2.11.2.

But I couldn't find the Scripts menu on the Web Admin Interface as indicated in the tutorial.

Got stuck and totally have no idea where to go from here.

The logs on GeoServer are as below:

```
2017-08-30 22:11:04,177 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'line'
2017-08-30 22:11:04,177 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'polygon'
2017-08-30 22:11:04,177 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'point'
2017-08-30 22:11:04,179 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'generic'
2017-08-30 22:11:04,179 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'raster'
2017-08-30 22:11:04,179 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded default workspace gc
2017-08-30 22:11:04,199 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'acme'
2017-08-30 22:11:04,209 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'gc'
2017-08-30 22:11:04,209 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'curing'
2017-08-30 22:11:04,491 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded store 'VISCA_QLD_500', enabled
2017-08-30 22:11:04,501 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'VISCA_QLD_500'
2017-08-30 22:11:05,707 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'QLD_VISCA500', enabled
2017-08-30 22:11:05,717 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'QLD_VISCA500'
2017-08-30 22:11:05,732 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'QLD_VISCA500'
2017-08-30 22:11:05,732 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded store 'VISCA_QLD_6000', enabled
2017-08-30 22:11:05,732 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'VISCA_QLD_6000'
2017-08-30 22:11:05,740 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'QLD_VISCA6000', enabled
2017-08-30 22:11:05,740 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'QLD_VISCA6000'
2017-08-30 22:11:05,742 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'QLD_VISCA6000'
2017-08-30 22:11:05,822 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Will look for 'geowebcache.xml' in directory 'C:\geoserver_data\gwc'.
2017-08-30 22:11:05,844 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in gwc
2017-08-30 22:11:05,844 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in gwc
2017-08-30 22:11:05,844 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in gwc
2017-08-30 22:11:05,946 WARN [config.XMLConfiguration] - ********************************************************************************
2017-08-30 22:11:05,946 WARN [config.XMLConfiguration] - *** GWC configuration validation error: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'gwcConfiguration'.
2017-08-30 22:11:05,946 WARN [config.XMLConfiguration] - *** Will try to use configuration anyway. Please check the order of declared elements against the schema.
2017-08-30 22:11:05,946 WARN [config.XMLConfiguration] - ********************************************************************************
2017-08-30 22:11:06,041 INFO [gwc.layer] - Initializing GWC configuration based on GeoServer's Catalog
2017-08-30 22:11:06,041 INFO [gwc.layer] - GeoServer TileLayer store base directory is: gwc-layers
2017-08-30 22:11:06,041 INFO [gwc.layer] - Loading tile layers from gwc-layers
2017-08-30 22:11:06,068 INFO [config.XMLConfiguration] - Initializing GridSets from gwc
2017-08-30 22:11:06,068 INFO [config.XMLConfiguration] - Initializing layers from gwc
2017-08-30 22:11:06,068 INFO [layer.TileLayerDispatcher] - Configuration gwc contained no layers.
2017-08-30 22:11:06,076 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - ********************************************************************************************************************
2017-08-30 22:11:06,076 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - *** Found Java environment variable GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR set to C:\geoserver_data, using it as the default prefix. ***
2017-08-30 22:11:06,076 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - ********************************************************************************************************************
2017-08-30 22:11:06,128 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Will look for 'geowebcache-diskquota.xml' in directory 'C:\geoserver_data\gwc'.
2017-08-30 22:11:06,145 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Will look for 'geowebcache-diskquota-jdbc.xml' in directory 'C:\geoserver_data\gwc'.
2017-08-30 22:11:06,148 INFO [diskquota.ConfigLoader] - DiskQuota configuration is not readable: gwc/geowebcache-diskquota.xml
2017-08-30 22:11:06,155 INFO [diskquota.ConfigLoader] - DiskQuota configuration is not readable: gwc/geowebcache-diskquota.xml
2017-08-30 22:11:06,158 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Setting up disk quota periodic enforcement task
2017-08-30 22:11:06,158 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - 0 layers configured with their own quotas. 
2017-08-30 22:11:06,158 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - 2 layers attached to global quota 500.0 MB
2017-08-30 22:11:06,210 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Disk quota periodic enforcement task set up every 10 SECONDS
2017-08-30 22:11:06,308 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WMTSInfoImpl--5c8c3f92:15e330d58c4:-8000', enabled
2017-08-30 22:11:06,311 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WCSInfoImpl--5c8c3f92:15e330d58c4:-7fff', enabled
2017-08-30 22:11:06,318 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WFSInfoImpl--5c8c3f92:15e330d58c4:-7ffe', enabled
2017-08-30 22:11:06,329 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WMSInfoImpl--5c8c3f92:15e330d58c4:-7ffd', enabled
2017-08-30 22:11:06,349 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WPSInfoImpl--497ff67b:15e30c3b557:-7ffc', enabled
2017-08-30 22:11:06,364 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WMTSInfoImpl--76991a5b:15e30b4af57:-7ff8', enabled
2017-08-30 22:11:06,372 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WCSInfoImpl--76991a5b:15e30b4af57:-7ff7', enabled
2017-08-30 22:11:06,379 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WFSInfoImpl--76991a5b:15e30b4af57:-7ff6', enabled
2017-08-30 22:11:06,389 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WMSInfoImpl--76991a5b:15e30b4af57:-7ff5', enabled
2017-08-30 22:11:06,434 INFO [gwc.config] - Initializing GeoServer specific GWC configuration from gwc-gs.xml
2017-08-30 22:11:06,752 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/gwc/service/**] onto handler 'dispatcher'
2017-08-30 22:11:06,834 INFO [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - Invoked setServletPrefix(gwc)
2017-08-30 22:11:06,856 INFO [georss.GeoRSSPoller] - Initializing GeoRSS poller in a background job...
2017-08-30 22:11:06,922 INFO [rest.RESTDispatcher] - Created RESTDispatcher with 15 paths
2017-08-30 22:11:06,989 INFO [wms.WMSService] - Will NOT recombine tiles for non-tiling clients.
2017-08-30 22:11:06,989 INFO [wms.WMSService] - Will proxy requests to backend that are not getmap or getcapabilities.
2017-08-30 22:11:07,025 INFO [georss.GeoRSSPoller] - No enabled GeoRSS feeds found, poller will not run.
2017-08-30 22:11:08,395 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/kml] onto handler 'dispatcher'
2017-08-30 22:11:08,395 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/kml/*] onto handler 'dispatcher'
2017-08-30 22:11:08,395 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/kml/icon/**/*] onto handler 'kmlIconService'
2017-08-30 22:11:08,871 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/ows/**] onto handler 'dispatcher'
2017-08-30 22:11:08,871 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/ows] onto handler 'dispatcher'
2017-08-30 22:11:08,881 INFO [org.geoserver] - GeoServer configuration lock is enabled
2017-08-30 22:11:10,211 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/wcs] onto handler 'dispatcher'
2017-08-30 22:11:10,211 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/wcs/*] onto handler 'dispatcher'
2017-08-30 22:11:11,646 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/TestWfsPost] onto handler 'wfsTestServlet'
2017-08-30 22:11:11,646 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/wfs/*] onto handler 'dispatcher'
2017-08-30 22:11:11,646 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/wfs] onto handler 'dispatcher'
2017-08-30 22:11:14,793 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/wms] onto handler 'dispatcher'
2017-08-30 22:11:14,793 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/wms/*] onto handler 'dispatcher'
2017-08-30 22:11:14,846 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/animate/*] onto handler 'dispatcher'
2017-08-30 22:11:14,846 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/animate] onto handler 'dispatcher'
2017-08-30 22:11:14,903 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/wps] onto handler 'dispatcher'
2017-08-30 22:11:14,903 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/wps/*] onto handler 'dispatcher'
2017-08-30 22:11:14,955 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/temp/**] onto handler 'filePublisher'
2017-08-30 22:11:15,061 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Found 30 bindable processes in Vector processes
2017-08-30 22:11:15,064 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Blacklisting process ras:ConvolveCoverage as the input kernel of type class javax.media.jai.KernelJAI cannot be handled
2017-08-30 22:11:15,072 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Blacklisting process ras:RasterZonalStatistics2 as the input zones of type class java.lang.Object cannot be handled
2017-08-30 22:11:15,072 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Blacklisting process ras:RasterZonalStatistics2 as the input nodata of type class it.geosolutions.jaiext.range.Range cannot be handled
2017-08-30 22:11:15,072 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Blacklisting process ras:RasterZonalStatistics2 as the input rangeData of type class java.lang.Object cannot be handled
2017-08-30 22:11:15,072 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Blacklisting process ras:RasterZonalStatistics2 as the output zonal statistics of type interface java.util.List cannot be handled
2017-08-30 22:11:15,073 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Found 17 bindable processes in Raster processes
2017-08-30 22:11:15,144 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Found 89 bindable processes in Deprecated processes
2017-08-30 22:11:15,147 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Found 5 bindable processes in GeoServer specific processes
2017-08-30 22:11:15,148 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Found 0 bindable processes in script
2017-08-30 22:11:15,154 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Found 48 bindable processes in Geometry processes
2017-08-30 22:11:15,209 WARN [geoserver.security] - security/masterpw.info is a security risk. Please read this file and remove it afterward
2017-08-30 22:11:15,720 INFO [geoserver.security] - Start reloading user/groups for service named default
2017-08-30 22:11:15,720 INFO [geoserver.security] - Reloading user/groups successful for service named default
2017-08-30 22:11:16,206 INFO [geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache Initialized with 1000 Max Entries, 300 seconds idle time, 600 seconds time to live and 3 concurrency level
2017-08-30 22:11:16,206 INFO [geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache Eviction Task created to run every 600 seconds
2017-08-30 22:11:36,073 WARN [geoserver.security] - Strong cryptography is NOT available
Download and installation the of unlimted length policy files is recommended
```

Comment: please look in the log file and add any errors there to your question

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the script menu for GeoServer v2.13.0 by adding the gs-script-web.jar to Geoserver/WEB-INF/lib since it wasn't present in the extension folder

You can get it from the link below:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geoserver.script/gs-script-web

Comment: in my case installing gs-script-web added the frontend menu item, but the extension was still not propably installed